# Is there an algorithm for "perfect" compression?

Tags: compression, entropy, information-theory

Let me clarify, I'm not talking about perfect compression in the sense of an algorithm that is able to compress any given source material, I realize that is impossible. What I'm trying to get at is an algorithm that is able to encode any source string of bits to it's absolute maximum compressed state, as determined by it's Shannon entropy.

I believe I have heard some things about Huffman Coding being in some sense optimal, so I believe that this encryption scheme might be based off that, but here is my issue:

Consider the bit-strings: a = "101010101010", b = "110100011010".

Using plain Shannon entropy, these bit strings should have the exact same entropy when we consider the bit strings as simply symbols of 0's and 1's, but this approach is flawed, because we can intuitively see that bitstring a has less entropy than bitstring b because it is simply a pattern of repeated 10's. With this in mind, we could get a better idea of the actual entropy of the source by calculating the Shannon entropy for the composite symbols 00, 10, 01, and 11.

This is just my understanding, and I could be totally off base, but from what I understand, for an ergodic source to be truly random, for an ergodic source with length n. the statistical probability of all n-length groups of symbols must be equally likely.

I suppose to be more specific than the question in the title, I have three main questions:

Does Huffman encoding using single bits as symbols compress a bitstring like a optimally, even with an obvious pattern that occurs when we analyze the string at the level of 2-bit symbols? If not, could one optimally compress a source by cycling through different "levels" (sorry if I'm butchering the terminology here) of Huffman coding until the best compression rate is found? Could going through different "rounds" of Huffman coding further increase the compression rate in some instances? (e.a. first go through Huffman coding with symbols that are 5 bits long, then going through Huffman coding for symbols that are 4 bits long? `huff_4bits(huff_5bits(bitstring))` )

Comment: Maybe you should change the question and remove the part about perfect compression. (Which is a valid question I guess, in relation to quantum computing.) By the way, do you know [arithmetic coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_coding)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As stated by Mark, the general answer is "**no**", due to Kolmogorov complexity. Let me expand a bit on that.

Compression is basically two steps :
1) Model
2) Entropy

The role of the model is to "guess" the next bytes or fields to come.
Model can have any form, and there is no limit to its effectiveness.
A trivial example is a random number generator function : from an external perspective, it looks like a noise, and therefore cannot be compressed. But if you know the generation function, an infinitely long sequence can be compressed into a small set of code, the generator function.

That's why there is "no limit", and Kolmogorov complexity just states that : you can never guarantee that there is not a better way to "model" the data.

The second part is computable : Entropy is where you find the "Shannon Limit".
Given a set of symbols (typically, the output symbols from the model), which are part of an alphabet, you can compute the optimal cost, and find a way to reach the proven ultimate compression limit, which is the Shannon limit.

Huffman is optimal with regards to the Shannon limit **if** you accept the limitation that each symbol must be encoded using an integer number of bits. This is close but imperfect approximation. Better compression can be achieved by using fractional bits, which is what Arithmetic Coders do offer, or the more recent ANS-based [Finite State Entropy coder](https://github.com/Cyan4973/FiniteStateEntropy). Both get much closer to the Shannon limit.

The Shannon limit only applies if you treat a set of symbols "individually". As soon as you try to "combine them", or find any correlations between the symbols, you are "modeling". And this is the territory of Kolmogorov Complexity, which is not computable.

Comment: So then does this mean that perfect compression is not possible? Or is it that you could compress something perfectly but not be able to know how much you've compressed it? Or does it mean that you can not calculate perfect compression save actually compressing perfectly?

Comment: There is a confusion risk regarding definition of "perfect compression". But if you mean "best possible compression ever" then the answer is a definitive no : you can never be sure that there is no better way to compress a given set of data. Maybe there is, and it just has not been found yet, or it could prove prohibitively CPU expensive for example. Even reaching such better version just pushes the mark : maybe *another* even better solution exist, and so on.

Comment: I liked this answer's discussing models and Kolmogorov complexity. I think it should be edited to state that Shannon entropy has a static model, not that it has no model. Wikipedia: "Although entropy is often used as a characterization of the information content of a data source, this information content is not absolute: it depends crucially on the probabilistic model... Kolmogorov complexity... allows the consideration of the information content of a sequence independent of any particular probability model; it considers the shortest program for a universal computer that outputs the sequence."

Answer (score 6):

No.  It can be proven that there is not even an algorithm to determine how well a perfect compressor will do.  See [Kolmogorov Complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity).

Huffman coding (or arithmetic coding) by itself does not get close to the best compression.  Other techniques need to be used to take advantage of higher order redundancies in the data.